# Use of "creator" property in timetime insert doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-mirror-api

The playground has an example card that includes a "creator" field with the name and an image representing "Google Glass". The JSON used to create this card is

```
{
  "text": "Hello Explorers,\n\nWelcome to Glass!\n\n+Project Glass\n",
  "creator": {
    "displayName": "Project Glass",
    "imageUrls": [
      "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-quy9Ox8dQJI/T3xUHhub6PI/AAAAAAAAHAQ/YvjqA3Pw1sM/glass_photos.jpg?sz=360"
    ]
  },
  "notification": {
    "level": "DEFAULT"
  }
}
```

When this is sent to Glass, however, the imageUrl isn't displayed. The documentation at https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/insert simply says that "creator" is a "nested object", but with no clear indication what this nested object should be. The example seems to indicate that this should be a Contact (see https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts), and the object returned by the insert seems to be of type "mirror#contact", confirming this.

Does the contact used in a creator need to be pre-created via the contacts API call first? Is there something else necessary to get the creator to display or work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creator is currently displayed only if the `REPLY` menu item is provided along with the timeline item.

This seems like a bug, please file it on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list)

Comment: Added as issue 83: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=83